opentelemetry.instrumentation.instrumentor - DependencyConflict: requested: "psycopg2 >= 2.7.3.1" but found: "None"
Has someone tried to get the OTEL for the PostgresSQL queries ? We have a fass-lambda that makes simple queries We are trying get info about how long the query took to execute by adding opentelemetry-instrumentation-psycopg2.  Adding psycopg2 to requirements.txt doesn't work. We get the following error:
    × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
-->   │ exit code: 1
-->   ╰─> [23 lines of output]
-->       running egg_info
-->       creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ngamcigt/psycopg2.egg-info
-->       writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ngamcigt/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
-->       writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ngamcigt/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
-->       writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ngamcigt/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
-->       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-ngamcigt/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
-->       
-->       Error: pg_config executable not found.
-->       
-->       pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
-->       containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
-->       option:
-->       
-->           python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
-->       
-->       or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
-->       
-->       If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
-->       'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
-->       
-->       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
-->       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
-->       
-->       [end of output]
-->   
-->   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
--> error: metadata-generation-failed
--> 
--> × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
--> ╰─> See above for output.
--> 
--> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
--> hint: See above for details.
--> make: *** [install] Error 1

So we replaced psycopg2 with psycopg2-binary (v2.9.9)
But, when we added opentelemetry-instrumentation-psycopg2, the official OTEL dependency for psycopg2, we get the following error and OTEL is generated:
[ERROR] opentelemetry.instrumentation.instrumentor - DependencyConflict: requested: "psycopg2 >= 2.7.3.1" but found: "None"

We are initiating the logs by adding the following line of code at the beginning of the file.
Psycopg2Instrumentor().instrument(enable_commenter=True)

Has anyone encountered this before ? Is there a work around?

It tells you what you need to do, you need to install psycopg2-binary to get both psycopg2 and the postgres binary installed for the connection to work

@C.Nivs psycopg2-binary has already been installed. It gives the above error even after installing psycopg2-binary.
